# htaccess for Angular app in a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I have an Angular 6 app living in a subfolder on a D8 installation. I have no issues navigating to the app and the angular routing doing it's thing as I navigate the app. My issues is I get a Drupal 404 if I try to hit the sub routes directly in the address bar.

What do I need to add to my htaccess that will let Drupal ignore the folder and the angular routing still work?

Drupal: `localhost:8888`

Angular: `localhost:8888/my-app`

**Things I've tried:**

Adding: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-app/.*$` **<- I get Not Found**

Changed `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm` to `DirectoryIndex index.php`

Adding the following to httpd.conf:

```
<Location "/my-app">
 FallbackResource /my-app/index.html
</Location>
<Directory /my-app>
 FallbackResource disabled
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following rewrite in your Drupal .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/APP-FOLDER-NAME/.*
```

Then in the root of the angular application folder you need the following in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /APP-FOLDER-NAME/index.html [NC,L]
```